# Multitouch with HTML5 with native support for Windows 7

Tags: html, windows-7, touch, virtual, multi-touch

I'm new to HTML5 and I'm trying to recreate this [light table](https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/light-table.php) which only supports iOS.

So the user can pinch and zoom in or out but I need it to support  Windows 7 native touch.

It seemed like its been [done before](https://vimeo.com/22110766) but no source code or a live site.

Any thoughts how I create that light table using HTMl5 but supporting Windows?